# JSON Destination component error in Kingswaysoft

Tags: json, ssis-2012, kingswaysoft

Am using JSON destination component to perform DELETE , it is a bit weird that the delete is successful when I saw in UI but am receiving the following error.

> [JSON Destination [15]] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: 
>    "System.Exception: Http response body is invalid JSON. (SSIS Productivity Pack, v6.2.0.1468 - 
>    DtsDebugHost, v11.0.7001.0)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.".
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "JSON Destination" (15) 
>    failed with error code 0xC02090F9 while processing input "Input1 (Merge Join)" (32). The identified component returned an error from the 
>    ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. 
>    There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Answer (score 0):

For the error you are getting above, it seems that the response you get is not in a JSON array, so the component cannot parse the response if you have checked the Response Is Array option in the Output Columns page.

Note that you would only check the Response Is Array option if the HTTP response contains an array with items corresponding to your input rows. If the response does not contain information about each input item, you wouldn’t need to check this option.

In this case, you can try to uncheck the Response Is Array option and enable the HttpBody option in the Output Columns page to verify what value you get from the response body.

Please feel free to reach out to our [official support channel](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us) if you have any further trouble.

Comment: I didn't check Response Is Array option but still am receiving the same error

Comment: We received your email to our support channel, one of our support members will get back to you shortly.